# Limiting results in Splunk

Tags: splunk

I am trying to write a splunk query(below) but limit the results to 100 events per cid. I can't use top and limit because it changes the output. This is what I have so far and I know I should be using | Head x but I am having a trouble with the syntax. Below Q will output everything for every cid but I am trying to limit that so I only get sample of 100 points per cid. I would really appreciate any assistance.

```
index=unruly_sampled_ad_stats (t=pp_play OR t=pp_completed_view OR t=complete OR t=q2 OR t=q3 OR t=q4 OR t=click) adf=* demand_partner=unruly
(cid=* ) (crid=*) (apid=*) (pid=*)
|bin _time span=1d
|lookup uas_lookup http_user_agent as user_agent
|replace "Mobile Browser" with Mobile in ua_type 
|replace Browser with Desktop in ua_type
|eval sampling_rate=coalesce(sampling_rate,1)
|eval play=if(t="pp_play",1/sampling_rate,0)
|eval pp_completed_view=if(t="pp_completed_view",1/sampling_rate,0)
|eval complete=if(t="complete",1/sampling_rate,0)
|eval click=if(t="click",1/sampling_rate,0)
|eval q2=if(t="q2",1/sampling_rate,0)
|eval q3=if(t="q3",1/sampling_rate,0)
|eval q4=if(t="q4",1/sampling_rate,0)
|stats sum(play), sum(pp_completed_view), sum(q2), sum(q3), sum(q4), sum(complete), sum(click) by adf, UID, apid, cid, crid, pid, ua_type, _time
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add top at the end of your query so that your results are limited to 100 for each cid after the stats have been calculated. It is little difficult to debug without the data but give it a shot.

```
|stats sum(play) as playSum, sum(pp_completed_view) as pp_completed_viewSum, sum(q2) as q2Sum, sum(q3) as q3Sum, sum(q4) as q4Sum, sum(complete) as completeSum, sum(click) as clickSum by adf, UID, apid, cid, crid, pid, ua_type, _time
|top 100 playSum,pp_completed_viewSum,q2Sum,q3Sum,q4Sum,completeSum,clickSum,adf,UID,apid,crid,pid,ua_type,_time by cid
```

Comment: Hey pjnike, thanks for looking into this. I tried putting top at the end but that where the problems lies. Top aggregates the results so all the stats get overwritten. I am sure that I have to use Head but if you help me with the syntax that would be awesome. Thanks again

Comment: I don't know if head is supposed to work with field names as far as the document says. what if you add `dedup 100 cid` after the stats? This will keep 100 rows per cid and discard the others.